# The residue of $\frac{\sinh(p^{1/2}(1-x))}{p\sinh(p^{1/2})}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

How would you calculate the residue of:

$$\frac{\sinh(p^{1/2}(1-x))}{p\sinh(p^{1/2})}$$

Where the variable of interest is $p$.

I think the poles are:

$p = 0 $ and $p = -(n\pi)^2$

I'm not sure how to go about even determining the order. I'm guessing the pole at $0$ is of order $2$ and all the other ones are of order $1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why $n\pi$? $\sinh \pi \not= 0$

Comment: What's the variable here? $p$? $x$?

Comment: variable is p. I just solved sin(i(p)^1/2) = 0

Comment: When does $\sinh{p^{\frac{1}{2}}} = 0$ ?

Comment: If it's not what i wrote, then i'm not sure :/

Answer (score 1):

The poles are simple and their residues can be evaluated accordingly.  For the residues at $p=-n^2\pi^2$ are given by

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{p\to -n^2\pi^2}(p+n^2\pi^2)\frac{\sinh((1-x)p^{1/2})}{p\sinh(p^{1/2})}&=\lim_{p\to -n^2\pi^2}\frac{\sinh((1-x)p^{1/2})}{\sinh(p^{1/2})+\frac12p^{1/2}\cosh(p^{1/2})}\\\\
&=\frac{\sinh((1-x)in\pi)}{\frac12 \cosh(in\pi)/(in\pi)}\\\\
&=-2\frac{\sin(n\pi x)}{n\pi}
\end{align}$$

The residue at $p=0$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{p\to 0}p\frac{\sinh((1-x)p^{1/2})}{p\sinh(p^{1/2})}&=\lim_{p\to 0}\frac{\sinh((1-x)p^{1/2})}{\sinh(p^{1/2})}\\\\
&=1-x
\end{align}$$